# Detect Text Language in the Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, internationalization

Given an input text-field, I would like to guess what is the language of the text the user inputs.

Most browsers supports the following API in extension mode - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/i18n/detectLanguage

However, I couldn't find how I could do this without an extension, just directly from my website.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using Google translate API to detect a language.
More on https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/detecting-language

Comment: I'd prefer the detection to be client-side, thanks.